# How to go back 10seconds onclick in Edge animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

Is there any function to get current time on timeline and go previous time we want.

I am trying to make previous button in Edge animate but there is only command `sym.play();`
and if enter time in  milliseconds like this `sym.play(3000);` it go 3 second on stage and play that.

So I want to back the time or want to go previous label.
Same thing to the forward button
i want to forward time by 10 seconds on timeline.

[Here](http://singhbalwant.com/lego/lego.html) is the link which i am creating.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current position of the playHead by sym.getPosition(), so if you
will use

sym.play( sym.getPosition() - 10000),

it should take you 10 sec earlier.
I would recommend working with labels, it may make your work easier.
Adobe edge api is [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/edge/api/current/EdgeAPI.0.1.6.html) , it's all there.